# Pandas: Improving corrupted matrix via transformation stuck

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_flat = pd.DataFrame({
    'dim1': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
    'dim2': ['H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3'],
    'val': [2, 4, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 6, 2.1, 2.2, 4.1, 3.4, 3.5, np.nan, 6.1, 2.3, 1.2, np.nan, np.nan, 2.4, 2.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.5]})

new_df = df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2']).unstack()
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

I am dealing with corrupted matrix (diagonal matrix), want to process the matrix. Matrix is to be read from right to lift for this case (as corruption is on left):

1. Check the value prior to corruption. For ex for row = 4,
   value prior to corruption is 6.1 (in H1).
   Find two closest value (in H1 column) in rows with no corruption (i.e. row 0, 1, 2).
   Take average of these two rows at H0 and H1 (Add this as extra col H0_miss, H_max_miss). Similarly, for row 5, value prior to corruption is 2.4, Find two closest value (in H2 column) in rows with no corruption (i.e. row 0, 1, 2).
   Take average of these two rows at H0 and H2 (Add this as extra col H0_miss, H_max_miss)

Expected Output:

```
df_flat = pd.DataFrame({
'dim1': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f','g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
'dim2': ['H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0_miss', 'H_max_miss', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0_miss', 'H_max_miss', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0_miss', 'H_max_miss', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0_miss', 'H_max_miss', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0_miss', 'H_max_miss', 'H0', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H0_miss', 'H_max_miss'],
'val': [2, 4, 3, 3.1, np.nan, np.nan, 3.2, 3.3, 6, 2.1, np.nan, np.nan, 2.2, 4.1, 3.4, 3.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.1, 2.3, 1.2, 4.05, 2.1, np.nan, np.nan, 2.4, 2.5, 3.2, 2.1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6]})

new_df = df_flat.set_index(['dim1', 'dim2']).unstack()
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Approach (Stuck actually):

```
a = new_df.to_numpy()
m = np.isnan(a)
col = m.argmin(axis=1)
```

Any way forward?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficent information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.